# $LR(k)$ grammar and handles

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I would like to understand in the snippet below why $\gamma\to aa$ has both handles
$(A\to a,1)$ and $(A\to a,2)$. The definition of a handle is on the top of the snippet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S\Rightarrow_R^* Aa$ (trivially, because $S\to Aa$). So $A\to a$ is a handle of $aa$ at position 1.

But also, $S\Rightarrow_R^* aA$ (again trivially, because $S\to aA$). So $A\to a$ is a handle of $aa$ at position 2.

Comment: OK, but how can I read off from (iii) that $i=\operatorname{lg}(\alpha\beta)$ is the **same as the  position** ?

Comment: @use122424: how do you read $lg(\alpha\beta)$? I'm reading it as the length of $ab$, which I would normally write as $\mid\alpha\beta\mid$. I don't know which textbook you copied (and you should correctly cite it, so it would be best if you edited the question), so I can't look up the author's terminology, but they certainly seem to be using it as the length operator.

Comment: Note that when I said "at position 2", I meant "at position 2 in the sentential form γ, not in the final derivation. Since $\alpha$ is what comes before $A\to \beta$ in $\gamma$, $|\alpha\beta|$ is precisely where derivation step ends.